# Select view only showing some results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an SQL view that is using this query:

`SELECT        dbo.FBAShipmentItems.ShipmentID, dbo.FBAShipmentItems.FNSKU, dbo.FBAShipmentItems.ASIN, dbo.FBAShipmentItems.Merchant, 
                         dbo.FBAShipments.ShipmentName, dbo.FBAShipments.Prep_Type, dbo.FBAShipmentItems.Quantity
FROM            dbo.FBAShipmentItems INNER JOIN
                         dbo.FBAShipments ON dbo.FBAShipmentItems.ShipmentID = dbo.FBAShipments.ShipmentID`

The problem is that it is only showing 56 results when I have close to 900 items in FBAShipmentItems and 51 in FBAShipments. How do I get all 900 results in my views

Comment: I'd be pretty concened that you appear to have shipment items that are not associated with a shipment and need to use a left join. Since you have no where clause in your query, there is no filtering, so you appear to me to have a serious data integrity problem. I suppose you don't have a foreign key relationship?

Comment: @HLGEM I use the ShipmentID which is unique to the shipment. You are right the insert was inserting wrong information but has since been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    items.ShipmentID,
    items.FNSKU,
    items.ASIN,
    items.Merchant,
    shipments.ShipmentName,
    shipments.Prep_Type,
    items.Quantity
FROM dbo.FBAShipmentItems AS items
LEFT JOIN dbo.FBAShipments AS shipments
ON items.ShipmentID = shipments.ShipmentID
```

This will return all rows from `FBAShipmentItems` together with the matching rows from `FBAShipments` if there are any, otherwise NULL for all values in that table.

Comment: And your query is much easier on the eyes as well. Aliases and formattting do makea difference.